# Распознавание речи на c++

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Для моего проекта нужна функция распознавания голоса, хочу реализовать её на C++, но не понимаю куда копать. Нашёл библиотеку CMUSphinx, но не понимаю, как её встроить в проект на C++. Еще есть Microsoft Speech Platform, но я так понимаю, что она работает только с C#. Как правильно использовать CMUSphinx или есть какие-то другие библиотеки?

Онлайн распознавание не подходит.